# Limit the CPU usage in shell_exec

Tags: php, cpu-usage, shell-exec

I need to limit the CPU usage for the following command since its using 100% of the CPU.

```
shell_exec("swfrender $swfFile -X 1600 -o $imageFile");
```

I found that I can use CPULimit and Nice, but I don't know how to set them up.

can anyone give me a simple example of how to limit the CPU usage of the above shell_exec task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A single look into the `nice` manpage reveals that you can use that command to start other commends with a specified nice level being set. So in your case I suggest you simply try this:

```
shell_exec("nice -n 19 swfrender $swfFile -X 1600 -o $imageFile");
```

I suggest you find out about the manpages installed on every unix like system. How to read them and how to find entries in there. Start by reading the manpage for the `man` command: `man man` :-)

Comment: a yep, I didn't knew nice, looks very... nice :-)

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, can you explain what does "nice -n 19" do? and also how to install nice or check if the system has already has it installed?

Comment: May I suggest _again_ that you start reading man pages? Sorry, but that would be just a quick glance in the manual for you! Just type `man nice` and read the documentation!

Comment: About the installation: just try to start `nice` from the command line. Or use `which nice` or `whereis nice`. Or you ask your package management system (depends on your linux distribution).

Comment: On _my_ system a `which nice` reveals: `/usr/bin/nice`, and then a `rpm -q --whatprovides /usr/bin/nice` shows that that file is part of the package `coreutils`. So check if you have that package installed if `nice` is missing on your system. Note that the package might be called slightly different depending on your distribution. and also it might be that your distribution does not use the rpm package manager. I myself use openSUSE distributions.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Linux, but I'll look into it. THANKS :)

Comment: Sure, trying things and looking around is the best way to get familiar. You will _love_ it :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `shell_exec` has virtualization features, there is no `shell_exec` option to do such a thing.

If you want to use [cpulimit](http://cpulimit.sourceforge.net/), that's ok but you'll need to do some tricks in PHP, and you'll need to release your `shell_exec` (eg. you will not wait for the end of the `swfrender` execution before your next code is interpreted by php).

Something like (i assume your $swfFile and $imageFile are `escapeshellarg`ized):

```
$pid = exec("swfrender $swfFile -X 1600 -o $imageFile >/dev/null 2>&1 & echo \$!");
exec("cpulimit --pid $pid --limit 65"); // 65%
```